# Save a theme (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, save, themes

Good morning,
Here I have two buttons that change the theme of my application (light and dark). When I reload my app the theme is not the one I selected last. I would like the application to back up the last theme used locally. You may need to save just a number that indicates which theme used the last one. . . But I don’t know at all how to do this?

Here’s the code: main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:watch/nav.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

import 'package:watch/blocs/theme.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
      builder: (_) => ThemeChanger(ThemeData.dark()),
      child: MaterialAppWithTheme(),
    );
  }
}

class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: theme.getTheme(),

    home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
      duration: 3000,
        splash: "",
        splashTransition: SplashTransition.slideTransition,
        pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.downToUp,
        nextScreen: Nav(),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

settings.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:watch/blocs/theme.dart';
import 'package:watch/constants.dart';

class Parametres extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeChanger _themeChanger = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Paramètres', style: kAppBarStyle,), 
        elevation: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => _themeChanger.setTheme(
                ThemeData(                 
                  bottomNavigationBarTheme: bNavBar,
                  scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBlackMedium,
                  brightness: Brightness.dark,
                  iconTheme: bIcons,
                )), 
              child: Text('Dark Theme')),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => _themeChanger.setTheme(
                ThemeData(
                  bottomNavigationBarTheme: lNavBar,
                  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  brightness: Brightness.light,
                  iconTheme: lIcons,
                  primaryColor: kWhite,
                )), 
              child: Text('Light Theme')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: you can use shared preferences to store key-value pair data. for example : isDark (key) - true/false (value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared preference is best option for it. Since I don't know about your ThemeChanger class I add here my theme class first:

```
class MyThemeModel extends ChangeNotifier{
  ThemeData _themedata;

  MyThemeModel(bool isActive){
    if(isActive == null){
      getThemeData;
    }
    else{
      if(isActive){
        _themedata = sleepTheme;
      }
      else{
        _themedata = morningTheme;
      }
    }

  }

  ThemeData get getThemeData => _themedata;

  void setThemeData(ThemeData data){
    _themedata = data;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**In main.dart**

```
void main() async{
  var isSleepActive;
  if(SharedPrefHelper.prefInstance.checkContains(SharedPrefKeys.ISMORNING)){
    isSleepActive = SharedPrefHelper.prefInstance.getBool(SharedPrefKeys.ISMORNING);
  }
  else{
    isSleepActive = false;
  }
  runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          builder: (context) => MyThemeModel(isSleepActive),
        )
      ],
    child: MyApp(),
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: Provider.of<MyThemeModel>(context).getThemeData,
      title: 'Theme App',
      home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
       duration: 3000,
       splash: "",
       splashTransition: SplashTransition.slideTransition,
       pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.downToUp,
       nextScreen: Nav(),
),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
```

In order to change theme with flat button:

```
FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => myThemeModel.setThemeData(
                ThemeData(
                  bottomNavigationBarTheme: lNavBar,
                  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  brightness: Brightness.light,
                  iconTheme: lIcons,
                  primaryColor: kWhite,
                )), 
              child: Text('Light Theme')),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Shared Preference package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and there you can store simple values as key pair values.Load that data in the init of the initial screen so that you can display the screen according to the theme

Answer (score 1):

You should use local memory to save theme.

You can use shared **preference** or **hive** db or **sqflite** or other database system.

**About changing theme you can use Cubit,Bloc,Provider or etc or even if ValueNotifier.**

However you should wrap your MaterialApp or CupertinoApp with "your state management widget"

And add some Logic

OR you can use some library
[Library to change theme](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_theme)